# Join Only Unique Values From 2 Tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to join two MySQL tables, and return only the unique values between them. eg.

```
Table1
column1|column2
-------------
c1value1|c2value1-1
c1value2|c2value1-2
c1value3|c2value1-3
```

```
Table2
column1|column2
-------------
c1value1|c2value1-1
c1value1|c2value2-1
c1value1|c2value3-1
c1value2|c2value1-2
c1value3|c2value1-3
```

I want to get as my result a table that *only* shows the intersections of rows without any duplicates where I'm joining on table1.column1 = table2.column1:

```
Joined Table
table1.column2|table2.column2
-----------------------------
table1.c2value1-2|c2value1-2
table1.c2value1-3|c2value1-3
```

Simple joins and unions and I'm ok, but this one is causing me a headache.

Edit for clarification:
I don't want any results in my joined table where Table 2 has > 1 entry in column 1. I only want to get back the values from column2 for c1value2 and c1value3.

My first thought was to get the distinct count of column2 GROUP BY column1 WHERE distinct count = 1 but that's error city.

Comment: Your desired output contains rows that are not present in your original data. Please update it. (`table1.c2value1-2` is not present in Table1, but it is in your Joined Table)

Comment: @Jesse You can use the DISTINCT operator to ignore duplicates

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you trying something like this:

```
 select t1.column2,t2.column2 
 from table1 t1 
 inner join 
 table2 t2 on t1.column2= t2.column2 
 where t1.column1 in ('c1value2', 'c1value3')
 group by t1.column2,t2.column2 ;

create table table1  (
  column1 varchar(50), 
  column2 varchar(50) );

insert into table1 values ( 'c1value1', 'c2value1-1'),
                          ( 'c1value2', 'c2value1-2'),
                          ( 'c1value3', 'c2value1-3');

create table table2  (
  column1 varchar(50), 
  column2 varchar(50) );

insert into table2 values ( 'c1value1', 'c2value1-1'),
                          ( 'c1value1', 'c2value2-1'),
                          ( 'c1value1', 'c2value3-1'),
                          ( 'c1value2', 'c2value1-2'),
                          ( 'c1value3', 'c2value1-3');
```

Demo: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/7yUJcuMJPncBBnrExKbzYz/70

Edit: If you want the unique values of column2 of both tables based on column1 of table1, you can use a subquery for selecting the distinct values for column1 and use it in the where condition.

```
 select t1.column2,t2.column2 
 from table1 t1 
 inner join 
 table2 t2 on t1.column2= t2.column2 
 where t1.column1 in (select distinct column1 from table1)
 group by t1.column2,t2.column2 ;
```

Demo: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/7yUJcuMJPncBBnrExKbzYz/72

Comment: I don't want to query using prior knowledge of the table, eg results that match a list of text I provide. Basically, I'm looking for a way to JOIN table2 with a SELECT that only returns truly unique rows (based on column 1): So because c1value1 is repeated, I only want to return c1value2 and c1value3 from table2. Hopefully that makes sense

Comment: @Jesse i updated the answer, check the edit part. I hope I understand you and I hope it helps

Comment: Awesome, thanks! I was working on a query to limit my return from Table2 and use that for where t1.column1 in (QUERY). Your approach still gave me dupe results in the final table, but replacing SELECT DISTINCT... with: SELECT column1 FROM table2 GROUP BY column1 ORDER BY COUNT(*) ASC LIMIT 2 did it. Thanks again!

Comment: It's a good idea to use fully-qualified names when doing a subquery within a `WHERE` clause: `where t1.column1 in (select distinct t1.column1 from table1)`.

Answer (score 2):

It's not clearly stated what must be unique? If you want to generate unique pairs here you go:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT t1.column2, t2.column2
FROM table1 t1
JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.column1 = t2.column1
```